# Creating Shared Tasks Folder Team

Tags: exchange-2010

Is it possible to create a shared task folder for a specific usergroup on an Exchange Server 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public tasks folder, then limit permissions on it to the security group that you want to have access. You could automate this with a combination of the Exchange Web Services API and (probably) some PowerShell or ADSI.